# android to qgis exchange data format

Tags: qgis-plugins, geojson, android, file-formats

I need to create a qgis plugin to import dip and dip direction data from an android compass app into an (existing) bedding data layer.

I need some suggestion about the best exchange file format; my idea would be to use QgsJsonUtils to import a GeoJson file, instead of using xml or csv format.

Comment: What format(s) have you tried?  What shortcoming(s) did you find?

Comment: I did't make any try nor find any shortcoming. I am involved in an academic project for which I have to develop a qgis plugin to import bedding data into qgis from a new android compass app; because I have to make it from scratch, I would be sure to make the appropriate choice on the exchange format.

Comment: Google recommends json or SQlite to store data in file system - so GeoJSON and GeoPackage is worth seeing.

Answer (score -1):

Geopackage would be the best format. It's sqlite3 supports rtree spatial index.

Comment: 1-Add a reference for the answer.  2-Describe in more detail.